# What is the simplest way to generate a dodecahedron?

Tags: mesh, modeling, geometry

I've been thinking of animating some dice and while most are easy to make, I'm having some trouble figuring out a way to generate a regular dodecahedron. I could hand build it but it would be potentially uneven. Would using the base of a 5 sided cylinder and then some variation on spin be the best option or is there a better way?

Comment: There's an add (extra object) capable of adding that primitive. You just need the plain result or something else?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Go to *User Preferences* and Navigate to *Add Mesh*, install the [*Regular Solids* addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Solid) and close the preferences window. Now if you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> you should see a new menu.

---

### UPDATE

In newer versions of blender (2.75 and up) the Regular Solids addon has been merged with the ***Extra Objects*** addon.

[image]

To create a dodecahedron go use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to *Add Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid*.

[image]

Then on the toolshelf you can select Dodecahedron.

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic add-on. It not only gives you dodecahedrons, but also octahedrons, diamonds, stars, and lots of settings for each, right below the "dodecahedron" drop-down.

Comment: when i uv unwrap this and limit the angles i still get extra vertice edges which form triangles, is there a way to create this object without the extra edges?

Answer (score 35):

If you don't want to use an addon, you can take advantage of the fact that the dodecahedron is the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron) of the icosahedron.

1. Add an icosphere (**Add** → **Mesh** → **Icosphere**) with **Subdivisions** at 1.
2. Go into edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
3. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to **Bevel** until you have an approximate dodecahedron:
   [image: approximate dodecahedron with bevel method]
5. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select **Remove Doubles**. Increase the **Merge Distance** until the vertex triples are merged. Et voilà; you have a dodecahedron.

Comment: Pretty creative, also fast. :)

Comment: Very useful for platonic/archimedean solids and similar things, thank you!

Comment: bang, simple quick, good.  if you use adding mesh technique you have to deal with removing edges, this is sweet.

Answer (score 15):

As @Carlo said it's available via Extra Object add on. If you want to make it from scratch though, here's how to do it.
[image]

Add an *Ico Sphere* and set its subdivisions to 1 in a Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

Give the object the ***Subsurf*** modifier with 1 subdivision and apply it.
[image]

Select the vertex in the center of a pentagon, go to *Select*-->*Select similar*-->*Amount of connecting edges*. It'll select all the vertices in the center of each pentagon.
[image]

Press <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Vertices* to get rid of them.
[image]

Now select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Limited Dissolve*.
[image]

Increase the *Max Angle* value in the *Limited Dissolve* panel of a *Tool Shelf*.
[image]

Comment: Pardon me for this unrelated comment, but: how do you obtain this shading?