# Rendering a 3D shape by positioning the camera on equidistant points on a dodecahedron

Tags: python, rendering, mesh, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I wonder, how can I render a 3D shape by positioning the camera on `X` number of equidistant (or almost equidistant) points on a regular dodecahedron in Python and using Blender's API? What I want to do is similar to the picture shown below as done in a [paper](https://github.com/Amir-Arsalan/Synthesize3DviaDepthOrSil) we have in a computer vision conference:

[image]

The code used for our previous project was written by my co-author and is in C++. However, for my new project I cannot use the C++ code he wrote for our previous work and my knowledge is limited in computer graphics. More specifically, I need help to write code for the following procedure:

Suppose a mesh like [this](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/0qdT2qakpfIytdnAGQg5Y7NkmHLKFsBnH4bda1lXR6w) is loaded into Blender. I first want to compute the camera distance to the **centroid** of the mesh. The centroid should be computed as the average of the mesh faces' centers, weighted by their area. How can I do that in Python? Then I want to compute `X` number of, equidistant, points on a dodecahedron so that I can position the camera using them and render the shape. `X` could be any even valid number for a regular dodecahedron (e.g. 20).

Comment: May be better suited to [Blender artists jobs forum](https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?51-Jobs)

Comment: 1) create the dodeahedron in blender 2) import or create your model 3) the script should just be about accessing the dodecahedron vertices and position to them for every frame (insert a keyframe for each vertex) and rotate the camera toward (look_at()) the model. What do you think? - btw: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-generate-a-dodecahedron