# Attaching faces of 2 tetrahedrons

Tags: snapping

I've learned some Blender and using it to model geometries with 4 isosceles triangles folded into tetrahedrons. The triangles are not intended to fold into complete, closed tetrahedrons. I'm hoping to get triangular meshes along the x and y axes to 'snap' together so further objects may be added to the construction.

I would be grateful to find a well supported, powerful, open source tool.

Where should I look, or what topic may be most relevant for me to explore to get this step done?

[image: two partially folded tetrahedrons to align]

Comment: In the Edit Mode you can select 2 vertices, and use Alt+M shortcut to merge them into one (small list of merging options depending on which vertex you selected first will appear, choose the option which suits your goal). This way you can join separate parts of the mesh. 

Using this method you can model complex shapes out of primitives (like cube), and there will be no need to manually align faces.

Comment: The [extra objects addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56/935) can create tetrahedrons for you. For the alignment look through the [snapping options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) - you want snap to face and the align to target to rotate it for you. You want to do the snapping in object mode, with the object origin at the base of the object.

Comment: thank folks.  in order to get the 2 objects shown in the pic I had to join all four isosceles triangles on each of them.  Then I appended one to the file of the other.  Seems after the joins I can't select the vertexes as recommened by Rumatta -  to have them snap together.